# PySpark is not releasing the memory in when I am running a deleting the dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, memory-leaks, pyspark

I am writing a code that loops over a data frame multiple times based on the timestamp extracted. The problem here is whenever outer loops run the memory is not freed in the spark. After collecting the data frame there are only 100 records. After four outer loops, my memory crosses more than 10G. I am new in spark.

```
infected = [3, 6, 127]
import gc
print("Grouping The value by timestamp")
all_value = {}
for level, value in enumerate(data_2020.select('timestamp').distinct().collect()):
  print(level, value)
  filter_condition = 'timestamp="{}"'.format(value.timestamp)
  sample_data = data_2020.filter(filter_condition).select('latitude', 'longitude', 'car_id')
  infected_df = sample_data.filter(sample_data.car_id.isin(*infected)).collect()
  sample_data = sample_data.filter(~sample_data.car_id.isin(*infected))
  sample_data = sample_data.withColumn("min_distance", lit(np.inf)).withColumn("infector", lit(np.inf))

  for base_df in infected_df:
    sample_data = sample_data.withColumn('current_infector',
            lit(base_df.car_id)).withColumn('base_latitude',
            lit(base_df.latitude)).withColumn('base_longitude',
            lit(base_df.longitude)).withColumn('base_latitude',
            f.round('base_latitude', 6)).withColumn('base_longitude',
            f.round('base_longitude', 6)).withColumn('distance',
            haversine_custom('latitude', 'longitude', 'base_latitude',
            'base_longitude')).withColumn('calculation',
            find_min_udf('min_distance', 'distance', 'infector',
            'current_infector')).withColumn('threshold',
            threshold_udf('min_distance')).select('latitude',
            'longitude', 'car_id', 'calculation.min_distance',
            'calculation.infector')
  all_value[value.timestamp] = sample_data.withColumn("threshold", threshold_udf("min_distance")).filter("threshold=1").collect()
  sample_data.unpersist()
  sample_data = None
  del sample_data
  spark.catalog.clearCache()

  infected = list(set([i.car_id for i in all_value[value.timestamp]] + infected))
  print("Level: {} \n Infected: {}".format(level, infected))
  gc.collect()
```

Comment: First of all, spark transformations are lazy evaluated (i.e. they are executed when required and not when submit). Secondly collect() and looping over a dataframe are bad practise. collect() pulls the data from your spark cluster to the python interpreter (inside the spark driver) (i.e. avoid it as often as possible). Looping creates often horrible execution plans. Try to rewrite your code and avoid loops and collect() and you will have a much smaller memory consumption.

Comment: Additionally the memory will be released when Spark context will be terminated

Comment: @cronoik thank you for the comment. The problem was the dag was getting too large and when the loop progressed. So I performed actions after each 5 loops and the problem was solved.